# How do I remove the customized icon from only one (or maybe more) app

Tags: gnome, icons, themes

Couldn't find this anywhere else...

I don't want to customize the original icon to another one. I want to stop using a custom icon set's specific icon and use the original icon only in ONE specific application (Discord).

Just to be sure:

I want to revert discord's icon to the original one but keep the rest of the custom icons provided by the theme in the home/.icons folder.

I tried just removing the icons named discord from the icon theme's folder but that just made discord's icon disappear.

How can I do what I want easily?

Or is it something hard enough for it to be easier to just use another icon theme whenever ONE or TWO icons don't match my taste or are so different from the original ones, that I can't even recognize the app anymore? :(

Answer (score 1):

With some fiddling around, I just found out how to easily do it. No commands.

If you have this same problem, know that we don't really have a "PROBLEM", because just deleting everything with the specific app's name from the icon theme folder will work...

BUT you have to delete the "icon-theme.cache" file and logout (or change to another icon theme and back to the one you're customizing) to see the changes apply.

I know I just answered my own question, but if you are trying to do the same, there you go.